# Should I call browser.Stop(); before calling browser.Load("url") function if browser.IsLoading == true?

Tags: cefsharp

While browser is loading a page initiated via JavaScript or user action, if I want to automatically load a new web page, should I call browser.Stop() before calling browser.Load("url") function if browser.IsLoading == true to be safe or is there a better way to solve this.

Comment: Safe from what exactly? Shouldn't be necessary to call `Stop/StopLoad` before calling `Load`.

Comment: For example: You want to crawl 10 specific web pages, where as, while your 6th page has been loaded successfully and your script is extracting data querying DOM elements, then automatically browser starts loading some unwanted page that many addressbar url change (could be a JS redirect), but your intent is to load your page #7 in the que.